# Facebook app don't show permissions and features when app live

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

I encountered a problem with my facebook application, when I tried to switch it to live mode, the app's rights and features were not displayed, in development mode, the permissions and features show normally. I'm sure the application and the permissions (manage_pages, publish_pages) have been evaluated and verified by the business, can someone help me, I'm really worried, i have posted some pictures below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution for this. I am facing the same problem. user_friends permissions is approved in app review and I have done business verification too but it still does not show in my permissions and features section in Live mode.

Comment: For my case, I signed the platform usage contract at https://www.facebook.com/business and everything is solved, you can ask questions at https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/ people are very enthusiastic.

Comment: Is that contract needs to be signed even after completing verification process?